# Incorrect Ouput for USACO December 2018 Bronze Back Forth

Tags: java, algorithm

USACO Bronze Problem from December 2018, BackForth problem: http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=857

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class backforth
{
    //  static int[] poss = new int[2000];
    static ArrayList<Integer> poss = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static void tuesday(int milk, ArrayList<Integer> one, ArrayList<Integer> two)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++)
        {
            int x = one.get(i);
//          ArrayList<Integer> twoNew = two; twoNew.add(x);
//          ArrayList<Integer> oneNew = one; oneNew.remove(i);
            two.add(x);
            one.remove(i);
            wednesday(milk - x, one, two);
        }
    }

    public static void wednesday(int milk, ArrayList<Integer> one, ArrayList<Integer> two)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < two.size(); i++)
        {
            int x = two.get(i);
//          ArrayList<Integer> oneNew = one; oneNew.add(x);
//          ArrayList<Integer> twoNew = two; twoNew.remove(i);
            one.add(x);
            two.remove(i);
            thursday(milk + x, one, two);
        }
    }

    public static void thursday(int milk, ArrayList<Integer> one, ArrayList<Integer> two)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++)
        {
            int x = one.get(i);
//          ArrayList<Integer> twoNew = two; twoNew.add(x);
//          ArrayList<Integer> oneNew = one; oneNew.remove(i);
            two.add(x);
            one.remove(i);
            friday(milk - x, one, two);
        }
    }

    public static void friday(int milk, ArrayList<Integer> one, ArrayList<Integer> two)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < two.size(); i++)
        {
            int x = two.get(i);
            int add = milk + x;
            if(!poss.contains(add))
                poss.add(add);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] hi) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("backforth.in"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("backforth.out"));
        StringTokenizer st;

        st = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
        ArrayList<Integer> B1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> B2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            B1.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
        }

        st = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            B2.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
        }
        tuesday(1000, B1, B2);

        //for(int  i = 0; i < poss.size(); i++)
        //  System.out.println(poss.get(i) + " ");
        System.out.println(poss.size());
        in.close();out.close();
    }
}
```

The output should be 5, but I am getting 9. I don't know how to fix the code to get the correct output--I tried several different ways, but I am not getting the correct output.

Possible milk output(s) I am getting for barn 1:

```
1008 
1004 
1007 
1003 
1005 
1000 
1001 
996 
997 
9
```

However, it should be `1000, 1003, 1004, 1007, 1008`.

Comment: It would be better to include the problem statement in the question if cooyright allows. We can be quite lazy with following links here. Also links tend to stale over time while we try to keep Stack Overflow a lasting knowledge resource.

Comment: Off the top of my head, the problem description says: "On Monday, Farmer John measures exactly 1000 gallons of milk in the tank of the first barn, and exactly 1000 gallons of milk in the tank of the second barn." I would think more carefully if and how that idea applies in the code's attempt to simulate different scenarios (in all functions, not just for `tuesday`.) It seems to me the iterations in the `for` loops may be acting on unexpected versions of `one` and `two`. Try logging them at the start of each iteration in the `tuesday` `for` loop, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is very much on the right track in formulating this as a [graph problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory); on a given day, you loop over every bucket in a barn and attempt to carry it, storing Friday's final results when unique.

However, for this to work, each time you carry a bucket from a barn and recurse on the child state, you need to "undo" the milk that was transferred when you return to the parent state. This way, when you try taking a different bucket on the next iteration, you'll have a fresh state to work from without pollution from previous recursive simulations.

Consider the following lines:

```
two.add(x);
one.remove(i);
wednesday(milk - x, one, two);
```

At this point in execution, the state has been permanently corrupted, meaning the origin state's buckets no longer match its input and any further computations in the loop will be inaccurate.

Instead, try restoring the state as follows:

```
two.add(x);
one.remove(i);
wednesday(milk - x, one, two);
one.add(i, two.remove(two.size()-1)); // undo the milk transfer
```

With this approach, after a call to `wednesday()`, the milk amount and buckets are restored to their original state and future iterations of the loop that test other buckets will do so accurately.

You can also copy these arrays before modifying them, which it looks like you attempted. This is the right idea and will also work, but it will be less performant than simply undoing each move and working with only two lists throughout.

Further, the code could use some reorganization, which might assist in understanding your program state, reducing duplication (potential bugs!) and easing refactoring.

There is no reason to have a different function for each day of the week because the same procedure is done on each day, namely, recursively attempt to carry each available bucket to the other tank. You can use a `day` variable to represent the current day, and increment it in each recursive call. If you begin at day `0`, your recursive base case is when `day == 4`, at which point you can record the final `milk` amount for that sequence of bucket choices. To determine which barn Farmer Brown is starting from on a given day, you can either take the modulus of `day` or swap the source and destination bucket arrays on each recursive call and find a way to add or subtract the milk amount depending on which barn you're in.

Lastly, `if(!poss.contains(add))` is a linear procedure that requires looking at up to every element in the list and is going to exact a huge performance hit on your result computation. Use a `HashSet` to store unique possible results. The size of this set is your final result.